# Don't understand proof that convergence implies Cauchy

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

So we are given that $x_n \rightarrow x$, so we can let $\epsilon = \epsilon'/2$ and there definitely exists an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|x_n - x| < \epsilon'/2$. Also by the triangle inequality, it suffices to show that $|x_n - x| + |x_m - x| < \epsilon'$. We know that $|x_n - x| < \epsilon'/2$, but we are given no information about $|x_m - x|$. It is possible that $\{x_m\}$ does not even converge, so I don't get how you can just claim that $\{x_m\}$ does converge without a separate proof/lemma.

Comment: hey, the $n$ in $x_n$ is an free variable; that is, $x_m$ is just another notation for $x_n$.

Comment: you want to write $e1 > e2/2$ dont you? so on the third line you know that the e2 < e1 ( e1 = epsilon e2 = epsilon prime in your example having some latex issues) either way your defiantly don't want an = sign on your line one cause then you cant show that it converges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is that you choose a *pair* of numbers, $n$ and $m$ such that $n\geq N$ for the appropriate $N$, implying you have both that
$$|x_n-x|<\varepsilon'/2$$
$$|x_m-x|<\varepsilon'/2.$$
From which point the proof follows by the triangle equality you set up. We're not saying $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon'/2$ because $n$ is special - we're saying that's true because $n$ is big (and so is $m$). That is, we're trying to prove something about the "tail-end" of the sequence using only that the sequence stays within arbitrarily small bounds. So, $n$ and $m$ are ranging over *the same sequence* - so it makes little sense to think $\{x_m\}$ is different from $\{x_n\}$, since we're trying to consider the values of a single sequence, at different indices. The reason we choose $n$ and $m$ arbitrarily, only restricted in that they must be at least $N$ is because to prove a sequence is Cauchy, we need to show that, for any $\varepsilon$, there is a big enough $N$ such that for any $n$ and $m$ larger than $N$, the difference $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: $n,m$ are chosen such that $n,m \ge N$ according to the statement of Cauchy sequences. $x_n$ and $x_m$ both refer to the same sequence $(x)$ but they could possibly refer to different components of the sequence. For example, when $m=n$ both indices refer to the same index and hence the same component. I hope this clears your questions.

Comment: This is like, lets say $(x)=(1,2,3,\dots)$. Then $x_1=1, x_2=2$.

Comment: The reason we choose $n$ and $m$ with only the restriction of it being big is from the definition of a Cauchy sequence; if we can't prove *any* two large enough values of the are sufficiently close, then we haven't proved its Cauchy - thus we *must* prove the statement for arbitrary $n$ and $m$ subject to only $n,m\geq N$. (@Sudarsan explains my comment on $\{x_n\}$ and $\{x_m\}$ being the same sequence quite well)

Comment: @Meelo doesn't that mean there might be different $N$ values for $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $x_m \rightarrow x$?

Comment: @user No. $N$ is chosen such that the property that $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon'/2$ holds for all $n\geq N$. If we chose $n,m\geq N$, we have the two premises we needed - neither may differ from $x$ by more than $\varepsilon'/2$.